# How to Use Python Requests Correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests, header

In python I currently have the following code:

```
s.cookies.clear()
s.post(page_url, data={'OP': 'LI', 'username': daniel, 'password': daniel123,
                       'g-recaptcha-response': user_answer['solution']['gRecaptchaResponse']})
time.sleep(1)
print(s.cookies)
```

When I run it I see many cookies being printed twice, why is that?

Comment: can someone accept my change?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `allow_redirects=True` in the arguments.

as that would take you to origin website instead of reading cookies off of a 302 response and trying to sleep on it.